# Object Transparency is not working on the principled bsdf

Tags: node-editor, transparency

can someone help me? 
i can't make my object transparent and i have alpha image, and translucency and i don't know where to put it...

i'm using cycle
blender 2.79b

i didn't connect the translucency and alpha
[image]

[image]

it worked on the material preview but doesn't even do anything
[image]

Comment: Does your Diffuse texture contain an actual alpha channel? I don't think so, cause you've got a separate Alpha texture. Try connecting the Color of the alpha texture, to the Fac of the mix shader.

Comment: oh it's actually work! 
yes, my bad thanks for your help and one more thing where do i put translucency?